# Active Direcory And Radius

Tags: networking, active-directory, radius

We have several websites and a user center for the authentication of them, for some reason, we are using the active directory to do the network control and group policy etc and we are trying to use the same username/password in both AD and website, so that we can access all our websites without log in again in the browser/another software.

Is there a solution that we can do the authentication in the same place?
We dont want to do the username/password sync, can the windows AD database get user data from my server, like Radius?

Answer (score 0):

You won't easily persuade Windows to get its SAM database from RADIUS. But you could configure your RADIUS server to authenticate to AD.

With FreeRADIUS for example this would mean configuring Samba and ntlm_auth or libwbclient, or trying and LDAP bind. You may have other possibilities with Microsoft's NPS.

You might be better to look at solutions that synchronise passwords between AD and your other user database, or standardising on just one of them and removing the other over time.